# Several /dev/loop in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 22.04, snap

In my Ubuntu 22.04 there's a lot of /dev/loop mounted files. I would like to know how can i delete all of them. Here's how its looks like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMLrC.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `/dev/loopX` entries are Snap applications that you have installed. If you really want to delete them, you must uninstall those applications.

Comment: Thanks for replied dude. Is there a problem in delete them? I'm a extreme newbie and  don't even know how i did that. Sorry

Comment: It's only a problem if you still want to use that application. Or if you "delete" random files instead of uninstalling the application properly.

Comment: I get it, but how can i find which applications are using or not those folders? I tried to share some files via FTP protocol and indeed i had to install some things but unfortunately i don't remember which were.

Comment: Ask Google: "*How do I list my Snap applications*"

Comment: I just run "snap list" and message says there's no app installed, then, i run losetup -a and show me this "/dev/loop3: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1623.snap (deleted))"

Comment: I remove the /dev/loop tagged as deleted and fix it. Thank you for your help bro.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of Ubuntu applications are now being distributed as snap applications, which show up as `/dev/loop%d` devices that are mounted.

You can't delete these directly, but you can uninstall the individual snap applications, or uninstall snap itself.

You *can* uninstall these, but should you?  As an admitted extreme newbie, you need to carefully consider if you really really want to remove functionality from your system, possibly crippling it and making the system unusable to the point that you end up reinstalling.

Really, what's the point in removing them anyway?

If those are safe to remove, there should be an eject button on the icon in the left bar in the filemanager.  If there is not, just ignore them.

Comment: I agree with you, and yes, i can unmounted via that button you've mentioned. The problem is that i wouldn't like to keep those folders in my left bar (as you can see through the attached image) and there's no option to remove that icons. Actually there's something that i didn't mention before, It did happen after that i tried to shared files via FTP protocol. My goal were transfer some of my photos in order make a backup and i just did messing up my left bar.

Comment: Making a research i found this command "losetup -a" which show up some of these lines "/dev/loop3: []: (/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core20_1623.snap (deleted))". All of them tagged as deleted.

Comment: I remove the /dev/loop tagged as deleted and fix it. Thank you for your help bro.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting things without understanding what's behind, usually ends up with broken things and, probably, with an unstable system. But you can hide those unmounted units from the Ubuntu Dock.

In Ubuntu 22.04, one easy way is opening `Settings`, clicking on `Appearance` (left side panel) and then clicking `Configure dock behavior`. The first section `Show Volumes and Devices` lets you tune what to see. I usually have it `On`, but I also uncheck **`Include Unmounted Volumes`**.

Another documented way is using the `gsettings` command from a terminal window to turn `show-mounts` off:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-mounts false
```

One problem with this second way is that no mounts will be shown at all, including those that refer to USB sticks, etc. It's a personal preference, but I like to see an icon when a USB stick is left plugged.